# Label axes on Seaborn Barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm trying to use my own labels for a Seaborn barplot with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
    
fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
fig = sns.barplot(x = 'val', y = 'cat', 
                  data = fake, 
                  color = 'black')
fig.set_axis_labels('Colors', 'Values')
```

[image: desired result]

However, I get an error that:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_axis_labels'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 407, accepted):

Seaborn's barplot returns an axis-object (not a figure). This means you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'val', y = 'cat', 
              data = fake, 
              color = 'black')
ax.set(xlabel='common xlabel', ylabel='common ylabel')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `seaborn` does not have its own way to set these - without involving `matplotlib` ?

Comment: So the general rule is `FacetGrid` / anything that facets returns a figure object and everything else returns an axis object?

Answer (score 73):

One can avoid the `AttributeError` brought about by `set_axis_labels()` method by using the **`matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel`** and **`matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel`**.

**`matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel`** sets the x-axis label while the **`matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel`** sets the y-axis label of the current axis.

**Solution code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
fig = sns.barplot(x = 'val', y = 'cat', data = fake, color = 'black')
plt.xlabel("Colors")
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title("Colors vs Values") # You can comment this line out if you don't need title
plt.show(fig)
```

**Output figure:**

[image]

Comment: I think it should be just `plt.show(fig)`. It gives me TypeError: show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Just `plt.show()` gives me the desired result

Comment: Doing it separately like this also has the advantage of specifying other miscellaneous [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties. I used it most commonly to specify a custom font that our organization uses by setting fontproperties equal to the location of the TTF file.

Answer (score 45):

You can also set the title of your chart by adding the title parameter as follows

```
ax.set(xlabel='common xlabel', ylabel='common ylabel', title='some title')
```

Comment: Is there a way to also change the font size of the labels and title within `ax.set()` ?

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing it, would be to access the method directly within the seaborn plot object.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'val', y = 'cat', data = fake, color = 'black')

ax.set_xlabel("Colors")
ax.set_ylabel("Values")

ax.set_yticklabels(['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'])
ax.set_title("Colors vs Values")
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The axis labels are the names of columns, so you can just `rename` (or `set_axis`) columns inside the `barplot` call:

```py
fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
sns.barplot(x='Values', y='Colors', 
            data=fake.rename(columns={'cat': 'Colors', 'val': 'Values'}), 
            #data=fake.set_axis(['Colors', 'Values'], axis=1), 
            color='black');
```

Another way is, since `barplot` returns the Axes object, you can just chain a `set` call to it.

```py
sns.barplot(x='val', y='cat', data=fake, color='black').set(xlabel='Values', ylabel='Colors', title='My Bar Chart');
```

[image: res]

---

If the data is a pandas object, pandas has a `plot` method that has a lot of options to pass ranging from titles, axis labels to figsize.

```py
fake.plot(y='val', x='cat', kind='barh', color='black', width=0.8, legend=None,
          xlabel='Colors', ylabel='Values', title='My Bar Chart', figsize=(12,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered with `set_axis_labels` is because there's no such function in Seaborn's `AxesSubplot` object. To resolve this issue, you can use the `set_xlabel()` and `set_ylabel()` methods provided by the Matplotlib axes object returned by Seaborn's `barplot`. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
fig = sns.barplot(x='val', y='cat', data=fake, color='black')

# Set custom axis labels
fig.get_xaxis().set_label_text('Values')
fig.get_yaxis().set_label_text('Colors')
plt.show()
```