# Can't plot comparative (double) histogram from Pandas table

Tags: python

Here's the table from the dataframe:

|  | Points_groups | Qty Contracts | Qty Gones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 350+ | 108 | 275 |
| 2 | 300-350 | 725 | 1718 |
| 3 | 250-300 | 885 | 3170 |
| 4 | 200-250 | 2121 | 10890 |
| 5 | 150-200 | 3120 | 7925 |
| 6 | 100-150 | 653 | 1318 |
| 7 | 50-100 | 101 | 247 |
| 8 | 0-50 | 45 | 137 |

I'd like to get something like this out of it:

[image]

But that the columns correspond to the 'x' axis,
which was built from the 'Scores_groups' column like this

[image]

I tried a bunch of options already, but I couldn't get it.

For example:

```
df.plot(kind ='hist')
plt.xlabel('Points_groups')
plt.ylabel("Number Of Students");
```

or

```
sns.distplot(df['Кол-во Ушедшие'])
sns.distplot(df['Кол-во Контракт'])
plt.show()
```

or

```
df.hist(column='Баллы_groups', by= ['Кол-во Контракт', 'Кол-во Ушедшие'], bins=2, grid=False, rwidth=0.9,color='purple', sharex=True);
```

Comment: Does this comment stackoverflow question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632637/label-axes-on-seaborn-barplot

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the distribution in your pandas dataframe, the plot you need can be achieved with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'A': [1, 2, 1], 'B': [2, 4, 3]})

X_axis = np.arange(len(Df['key']))

plt.bar(X_axis - 0.2, Df['A'], 0.4, label = 'A')
plt.bar(X_axis + 0.2, Df['B'], 0.4, label = 'B')

X_label = list(Df['key'].values)
plt.xticks(X_axis, X_label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Since I don't have access to your data, I made some mock dataframe. This results in the following figure:

[image]